# What do you use as an alternative for "In light of"?

Tags: synonyms

What do you use as an alternative for "In light of" in this context?

**In light of** the recent evidence, the police arrested John Smith.

Comment: "The police arrested John Smith *because of* the recent evidence."

Comment: How about "Given"? Given recent evidence, the police . . ..

Answer (score 5):

*due to*, *considering*, *on account of*, or *because of* would be fine.

I see no problem with the way you have it, unless of course you are looking for variation in your writing.

Comment: Thanks. It is for paraphrasing a sentence that I read in a research paper. In my case, I would like to use "In light of" but I am afraid it would be considered copying.

Answer (score 0):

other variations are

[owing to](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/owing+to?s=t)

[in view of](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/In+view+of?s=t)

Comment: Please offer more than a one-line answer. We prefer an answer which gives a good explanation or good reasons *why* it is correct.

Comment: There is a certain jouissance in the play of words that very often defies rational explanation - chill and have fun with words

Comment: Wordplay is not discouraged, but definitely plays second fiddle to rational explanations. There's a lot more wordplay in [chat]. Answers should be based primarily on "facts, references, and specific expertise". Also, "links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline".

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion would be:

> With this in mind, ...

Comment: Please offer more than a one-line answer. We prefer an answer which gives a good explanation or good reasons why it is correct.

Comment: Very good suggestion and yet not the definitive answer this site expects under the category Answer. Usually a tossed-off response goes in a Comment. That is what Sinosohn is remarking on re explanation and reasons.